# Disable Bootstrap tab with eventkey in ract.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, react-bootstrap

I am using `React Bootstrap` in my `react.js` page. I want to disable tabs based on a button click and i don't want set default disable attribute. 
Is there any way

```
<Tabs activeKey={this.state.key} onSelect={this.handleSelect} id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
      <Tab eventKey={1} title="Customer" className="studenttab">
      </Tab>
      <Tab eventKey={2} title="Customer" className="admintab">
      </Tab>
     <Tab eventKey={3} title="Customer" className="othertab">
      </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Comment: should all tabs be disabled after a click on any one of them?

Comment: no, it like if admin is logged admin tab is active and other two tabs should be disabled on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to pass a boolean prop `isAdmin` to the parent component that tells, whether the current user is admin and then use it in the component:

```js
<Tabs activeKey={this.state.key} onSelect={this.handleSelect} id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
      <Tab eventKey={1} title="Student" disabled={this.props.isAdmin} className="studenttab" />
      <Tab eventKey={2} title="Admin" className="admintab" />
     <Tab eventKey={3} title="Other" disabled={this.props.isAdmin} className="othertab" />
</Tabs>
```

Comment: Could you please set the answer as correct? Thanks!